# Kivy with Buildozer has error while packaging a simple application

Tags: android, python-2.7, kivy

I've just started learning Kivy and am trying to compile my first application. It's a super simple application that I have copied from a beginner tutorial. When I use

```
buildozer --verbose android debug
```

I get the following error

```
# Package the application
# project.properties updated
# Run '/usr/bin/python build.py --name TestApp --version 1.2.0 --package org.test.testapp --private /home/aphid/orkiv/.buildozer/android/app --sdk 14 --minsdk 8 --orientation sensor debug'
# Cwd /home/aphid/orkiv/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/dist/testapp
  File "build.py", line 186
    print '%s: %s' % (tfn, fn)
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
# Command failed: /usr/bin/python build.py --name TestApp --version 1.2.0 --package org.test.testapp --private /home/aphid/orkiv/.buildozer/android/app --sdk 14 --minsdk 8 --orientation sensor debug
```

I initially thought it may have been a dependencies problem, but I've checked and I'm pretty sure I have everything required (javac etc, along with 32bit dependencies). So at this point I'm lost.

I'm using Arch Linux and buildozer with python2.7.

Here's the buildozer.spec:

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = TestApp

# (str) Package name
package.name = testapp 

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.test

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
#version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
#version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
version = 1.0

# (list) Application requirements
# comma seperated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = kivy

# (list) Garden requirements
#garden_requirements =

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.png

# (str) Icon of the application
#icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, portrait or all)
orientation = all

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 1


#
# Android specific
#

# (list) Permissions
#android.permissions = INTERNET

# (int) Android API to use
#android.api = 20

# (int) Minimum API required (8 = Android 2.2 devices)
#android.minapi = 8

# (int) Android SDK version to use
#android.sdk = 21

# (str) Android NDK version to use
#android.ndk = 9d

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
#android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ndk_path =

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.sdk_path =

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
#android.p4a_dir =

# (list) python-for-android whitelist
#android.p4a_whitelist =

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.renpy.android.PythonActivity

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, if not master, useful to try
# not yet merged features.
#android.branch = master

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters =

# (list) Android additionnal libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
#android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
#android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
#android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
#android.meta_data =

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =

#
# iOS specific
#

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
# Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
#ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer: <lastname> <firstname> (<hexstring>)"

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s


[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 1

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 1


#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    List as sections
#
#    You can define all the "list" as [section:key].
#    Each line will be considered as a option to the list.
#    Let's take [app] / source.exclude_patterns.
#    Instead of doing:
#
#[app]
#source.exclude_patterns = license,data/audio/*.wav,data/images/original/*
#
#    This can be translated into:
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns]
#license
#data/audio/*.wav
#data/images/original/*
#


#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Profiles
#
#    You can extend section / key with a profile
#    For example, you want to deploy a demo version of your application without
#    HD content. You could first change the title to add "(demo)" in the name
#    and extend the excluded directories to remove the HD content.
#
#[app@demo]
#title = My Application (demo)
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns@demo]
#images/hd/*
#
#    Then, invoke the command line with the "demo" profile:
#
#buildozer --profile demo android debug
```

I've googled the hell out of this but can't even seem to work out exactly what the error means. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I know you said you use python2.7, but this line print '%s: %s' % (tfn, fn) looks like a python3 error.

Comment: I'll echo Duikboot's comment, especially since Arch linux names the python3 executable just 'python'. However, while this was an issue several months ago, I didn't think it was any more.

Comment: I think you're right - I must be using python3. But buildozer should support python3 (from what I've read it does). So what could be causing the error?

Comment: The print statement is always an error in python3, so it should be clear that buildozer does not support it. The installation instructions on GH even reference python2.7 specifically.

Comment: I think we officially state buildozer works with python3, but this actually means only in the context that buildozer's own scripts will run (in particular, buildozer-remote and tito's hanga additions). To build your own apks, I think you must use python2.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is that using buildozer on Arch isn't as simple as just installing it. I followed the directions [in this Github post](https://github.com/aminb/site-legacy-camporez-based/blob/master/_posts/2014-05-03-arch-kivy-buildozer.md) for getting buildozer to work on Arch and that seemed to fix the problem.

Comment: the link is dead.